# To establish sql-connection from jUnit test

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, junit

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3. PostgreSQL driver is `postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar`.

I need to write jUnit test which establishes sql-connection and aggregating data from a database. The following `@Test` method I've written:

```
@Test
public void todayStatisticTest() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", "postgres");
    connectionProps.put("password", "password");
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); //ClassNotFound exception is thrown
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db_name", connectionProps);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM partner.partner");
}
```

Why is `ClassNotFoundExpcetion` thrown?

Comment: Could you provide the full error description?

Comment: did you really add org.postgresql.Driver ?

Comment: Mind looking into the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html)? Additionally, this question lacks some info: How are you running your tests? How are you making sure, that the JAR file containing the driver is part of the class path? Difficult to help without knowing the circumstances.

Comment: Are those versions right? PostgreSQL 9.3 but the driver is for **8.3**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably did not provide all required jars on the classpath when starting the junit test. You need to make sure that the postgresql driver jar is also on the classpath during the run of your test. Depends on what IDE you use, or if you are running it on command line you have to add it to the -cp parameter (this is actually what the IDE will do for you).

Comment: Huh, you're absolutely right. I've add it to a classpath and it works. Thankk you.